# App keeps on crashing

Tags: java, android

I've got all of my code now but keeps on crashing. Basically, the code is a button that, when clicked, will add a number to an amount. So, when clicked once, it will be 1; clicked again will become 2, then 3, and so on like a ticker.

```
package com.example.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Private member field to keep track of the count
private int mCount = 0;

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.myApp.mCount";
private SharedPreferences settings = null;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;

/** ADD THIS METHOD **/
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  // Always call the superclass method first
  settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
  mCount = settings.getInt("mCount", 0);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
  editor = settings.edit(); /** ADD THIS LINE **/
  editor.putInt("mCount", mCount);
  editor.commit();
}
}
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:text="Count" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Would you like to post your LogCat stack trace? Without that, we can only guess.

Answer (score 2):

You should be creating the `SharedPreferences` object in `onCreate()`; before then, it's not guaranteed to be created.

Additionally, you should be calling `edit()` in every `onResume()`; otherwise, you will likely get old data in that `Editor`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Private member field to keep track of the count
    private int mCount = 0;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.myApp.mCount";
    private SharedPreferences settings = null;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;

    /** ADD THIS METHOD **/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  // Always call the superclass method first
      settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
      mCount = settings.getInt("mCount", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
      editor = settings.edit(); /** ADD THIS LINE **/
      editor.putInt("mCount", mCount);
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: @James I've made an edit to the code above; try it now. If it's still not working, update your initial post with the updated code and LogCat.

Comment: ok right ive updated my code to the code im now using but its now stable but theres no button to click to be the ticker and no text box ive also put the xml in the updated version

Comment: You've added no code to the `Button` to increase the counter. Have a look at a [`Button` listener tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/). This portion is beyond the scope of this question, though, so if you need help with it, you should close this question (by accepting an answer with the checkmark), then start a new one.

Comment: ahhh ok ill look into it thanks so much for your help so this code will save the amount in the ticker when closed?

Comment: @James The code you have now? Yes. It will save the value of `mCount` when closed or switched via task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Always check that your variables (`settings`, `editor`) are not null ...

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
  mCount = settings.getInt("mCount", 0);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
  editor.putInt("mCount", mCount);
 editor.commit();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying moving the getSharedPreferences into Activity.onCreate I don't think it can be done before this.

```
// Private member field to keep track of the count
private int mCount = 0;

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.myApp.mCount";
private SharedPreferences settings;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here

Do like this. I hope it wil help you.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.layout);
   ..some code.
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   Editor editor = settings.edit();
 }
```